# I am unable to split apparently linked data into individual components in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have extracted some data from the internet:

[image]

```
In [25]:

df.dtypes
Out[25]:
Dividend    float64
dtype: object
```

I can manipulate the Dividend data:

```
In [28]:

df['try']=df['Dividend']*2
In [31]:

df['try'].head()
Out[31]:
Date
1962-02-06    0.00200
1962-05-08    0.00200
1962-08-07    0.00200
1962-11-05    0.00200
1963-02-05    0.00266
Name: try, dtype: float64
```

But I don't know how to "de-link" the date with the Dividend data.  I want to use the Dividend number in another equation without having a tie to the date.

Comment: Sorry are you asking just for the values? if so then `df['try'].values` will return a np array representation

Comment: Thanks Ed, I knew there had to be a way to get the data.  Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Date` is the `index`, or row labels of the dataframe. The index
should only affect the use of the dividend data if you are merging or joining
(and then it is a good thing to keep the index, so that you can perform correct
merges).

You can read more about indices
[here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html)

You can access the index through the `index` attribute

```
## get index
df.index
## assign new index based on row number
df.index = range(df.shape[0])
```

Post a reproducible example of what is going wrong if this does not help.

Comment: Thanks ajerneck, that worked and is what I needed.  I guess I did not realize that date was an index . . .had my blinders on ;-)